# Javascript global scope variables accessed later in a script tag with src

Tags: javascript, php, global-variables, global-scope

I want to be able to pass variables from php into my javascript code in order to save a given users high score. I have done that successfully by at the top of my page by declaring:

```
<?php
    session_start();


    $bricks = $_SESSION["bricks"];
    require 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
    require 'save.php';


?>
```

SESSION['bricks'] is the high-score in the database. A the end of of the html code within the php code I have my entire game written within a script tag. In the game

```
this.highScore = "<?php echo $bricks?>";
```

But this is long and messy. Lets say I wanted to replace the long script tag with a `<script src="myGame.js"></script>` this would be problematic because the file would no longer be a php file and would not be able to grab the session variable bricks.

When using the global scope I can grab the variable highscore from the session variable

```
<script> var highScore = <?php echo $bricks;?>;</script>
```

then later:

```
<script>console.log(highScore)</script>
```

but if I make the second script tag link to a source:

```
<script src="myGame.js"></script>
```

I will not be able to access that variable highScore in myGame.js. Is there a way to pass a variable from a script tag at the top of your page into a script tag with an src attribute and access that variable within the javascript document that is linked? there is a workaround, but I want to know if I can make it more manageable this way.

Comment: _“this would be problematic because the file would no longer be a php file”_ - well then _make_ it one. `myGame.php`, make it output the correct Content-Type header for a JavaScript resource first, and then the actual JS code - created dynamically, however you like … https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531311/how-can-i-generate-dynamic-javascript

Answer (score 1):

First make your js code stable:

```
var highScore = parseInt("<?php echo $bricks;?>");
```

In your javascript `object` try set global variable highScore to object's property :

```
this.highScore = highScore;
```